# How to properly send and receive "POST" requests to and from a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, http

I am trying to make a server for a website. The server works perfectly, and it can receive and send data normally. I have hosted the server, and I made a demo client-side repl on Replit to test the flow. But somehow, either the reply isn't receiving or sending properly, or the server isn't working. (For the client-side code, I am using JQuery)

```
// Client Side Code
const url = "My url";
const data = {
    "file": "lol.html"
}

function start() {
    console.log("test 1")
    $.post(url, data, function(data, status) {
        console.log(data + "is data & status is " + status);
    });
}
```

```
// Server-side code
var http = require('http'); // Import Node.js core module
var fs = require('fs'); // File System
var url = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {   //create web server
    if (req.url == '/') { //check the URL of the current request

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.write(JSON.stringify({ message: "This is the Backend server for my website" }));
        res.end();

    }
    else if (req.url == "/ping") {

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.write(JSON.stringify({ message: "Pong!" }));
        res.end();

    }
    else if (req.url.startsWith("/read")) {

        var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
        var qdata = q.query;
        fs.readFile(String(qdata.file), function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                return res.end("404 Not Found");
            }
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.write(data);
            return res.end();
        });
    }
    else if (req.url.startsWith("/get")) {

        var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
        var qdata = q.query;
        fs.readFile(String(qdata.file), function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                return res.end("404 Not Found");
            }
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.write(data);
            return res.end();
        });
    }
    else {
        res.end('Invalid Request!');
    }

});

server.listen(5000); //6 - listen for any incoming requests

console.log('Node.js web server at port 5000 is running..')
```

**Can Someone tell me how to perform this properly?**

Comment: `const url = "My url";`
You are not looking for this string in any of your if blocks.

Comment: uh, the server-side code? I am sending the url as https://myserverurl.com/read

Comment: The URL you use with `$.post()` should be a full URL like `http://somedomain.com/read`.  If that server isn't also the server that your web page came from, then you have cross origin (CORS) issues to deal with because the browser may not let you make the request.   You don't show how the web page that is running this script gets loaded for us to advise on that part of the issue.  FYI, my recommendation is to use the `fetch()` [interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) in the browser, not jQuery.